# How do I construct an ISO 8601 datetime in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, azure

I'm working with the Azure REST API and they are using this to create the request body for table storage:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")
```

Which produces:

> 2012-03-02T04:07:34.0218628Z

It is called "round-trip" and apparently it's an ISO standard (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) but I have no idea how to replicate it after reading the wiki article.

Does anyone know if [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) has support for this, or possibly [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/)?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If the time to the nearest second is precise enough, you can use `strftime`:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    char buf[sizeof "2011-10-08T07:07:09Z"];
    strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%FT%TZ", gmtime(&now));
    // this will work too, if your compiler doesn't support %F or %T:
    //strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", gmtime(&now));
    std::cout << buf << "\n";
}
```

If you need more precision, you can use Boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    ptime t = microsec_clock::universal_time();
    std::cout << to_iso_extended_string(t) << "Z\n";
}
```

Comment: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ` is equivalent to `%FT%TZ` for those who still have to cope with a C++03 compiler

Answer (score 59):

Using the [date](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library (C++11):

```
template <class Precision>
string getISOCurrentTimestamp()
{
    auto now = chrono::system_clock::now();
    return date::format("%FT%TZ", date::floor<Precision>(now));
}
```

Example usage:

```
cout << getISOCurrentTimestamp<chrono::seconds>();
cout << getISOCurrentTimestamp<chrono::milliseconds>();
cout << getISOCurrentTimestamp<chrono::microseconds>();
```

Output:

```
2017-04-28T15:07:37Z
2017-04-28T15:07:37.035Z
2017-04-28T15:07:37.035332Z
```

Comment: This only works for C++11 and C++14

Answer (score 26):

With C++20, time point formatting (to string) is available in the (chrono) standard library.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
   std::cout << std::format("{:%FT%TZ}", now) << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
2021-11-02T15:12:46.0173346Z
```

It works in Visual Studio 2019 with the latest C++ language version (/std:c++latest).

Answer (score 14):

I should point out I am a C++ newb.

I needed string with a UTC ISO 8601 formatted date and time that included milliseconds. I did not have access to boost.

This is more of a hack than a solution, but it worked well enough for me.

```
std::string getTime()
{
    timeval curTime;
    gettimeofday(&curTime, NULL);

    int milli = curTime.tv_usec / 1000;
    char buf[sizeof "2011-10-08T07:07:09.000Z"];
    char *p = buf + strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%FT%T", gmtime(&curTime.tv_sec));
    sprintf(p, ".%dZ", milli);

    return buf;
}
```

The output looks like: **2016-04-13T06:53:15.485Z**

Comment: I think you want to use `sprintf(p, ".%03dZ", milli);` to print the milliseconds correctly.

Answer (score 5):

In Qt, that would be:

```
QDateTime dt = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
dt.setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC);  // or Qt::OffsetFromUTC for offset from UTC
qDebug() << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(Qt::ISODate);
```

Comment: The numbers in the end is the issue, not the format of the string

Comment: You mean the fractional part of the seconds (i.e. .0218628)? They are optional...

Comment: how? could not see anything in the doc

Comment: at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times : "Decimal fractions may also be added..."

Comment: Yeah, I fully aware of that. I just wonder how to do it using the Qt approach.

Comment: Ah ok. In most c++ toolkits, time is defined using epoch (time_t, QTime, ...). It is only precise up to the second, so it doesn't make sense (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: Why does your last line call QDateTime::currentDateTime() instead of using dt: qDebug() << dt.toString(Qt::ISODate);

Answer (score 4):

Boost has a [library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time.html) for this.

I.e. [posix_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) has the `from_iso_string()` and `to_iso_string()` functions.

Answer (score 2):

OK so I've modified a few solutions that I've found as came up with the following :

```
static QString getTimeZoneOffset()
{
    QDateTime dt1 = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    QDateTime dt2 = dt1.toUTC();
    dt1.setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC);

int offset = dt2.secsTo(dt1) / 3600;
if (offset >= 0)
    return QString("%1").arg(offset).rightJustified(2, '0',true).prepend("+");
return QString("%1").arg(offset).rightJustified(2, '0',true);
}
```

Then to easily format a date ( **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ** ) :

```
static QString toISO8601ExtendedFormat(QDateTime date)
{
    QString dateAsString = date.toString(Qt::ISODate);
    QString timeOffset =  Define::getTimeZoneOffset();
    qDebug() << "dateAsString :" << dateAsString;
    qDebug() << "timeOffset :" << timeOffset;
    timeOffset = QString(".000%1%2").arg(timeOffset).arg("00");
    qDebug() << "timeOffset replaced :" << timeOffset;
    if(dateAsString.contains("Z",Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        dateAsString = dateAsString.replace("Z",timeOffset);
    else
        dateAsString = dateAsString.append(timeOffset);
        qDebug() << "dateAsString :" << dateAsString;
    return dateAsString;
}
```

For example GMT +2 would look like this :
**2013-10-14T00:00:00.000+0200**

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function which uses `std::put_time` with a `std::ostringstream` to generate the resulting `std::string`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
/**
 * Generate a UTC ISO8601-formatted timestamp
 * and return as std::string
 */
std::string currentISO8601TimeUTC() {
  auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto itt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << std::put_time(gmtime(&itt), "%FT%TZ");
  return ss.str();
}
// Usage example
int main() {
    std::cout << currentISO8601TimeUTC() << std::endl;
}
```

Reference: https://techoverflow.net/2018/03/30/iso8601-utc-time-as-stdstring-using-c11-chrono/

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Visual C++, GNU C++, Emscripten

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream> 
#include <locale>  

#if defined (_WIN32) 
#define WINDOWSLIB 1
#elif defined (__APPLE__)//iOS, Mac OS
#define MACOSLIB 1
#elif defined (__LINUX__) || defined(__gnu_linux__) || defined(__linux__) || defined(__linux) || defined(linux)//_Ubuntu - Fedora - Centos - RedHat
#define LINUXLIB 1
#elif defined (__EMSCRIPTEN__)
#define EMSCRIPTENLIB 1
#endif

#define WriteLine(data)std::cout<< data <<std::endl;
typedef std::string String;

String CurrentISO8601DateTime(bool toUTC=true)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
    time_t timet = system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::tm tm{};
    String localeStr = setlocale(LC_ALL, nullptr);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, u8"");
    String format = String(u8"%FT%T.").append(std::to_string(duration_cast<milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count() % static_cast<long long>(1000)));
    if (toUTC)
    {
#ifdef WINDOWSLIB
        gmtime_s(&tm, &timet);
#elif LINUXLIB
        gmtime_r(&timet, &tm);
#elif EMSCRIPTENLIB
        gmtime_r(&timet, &tm);
#endif
        format = format.append(u8"Z");
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef WINDOWSLIB
        localtime_s(&tm, &timet);
#elif LINUXLIB
        localtime_r(&timet, &tm);
#elif EMSCRIPTENLIB
        localtime_r(&timet, &tm);
#endif
        format.append(u8"%z");
    }
    String result = String(255, 0);
    const size_t length = std::strftime(&result[0], result.size(), format.c_str(), &tm);
    result.resize(length);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, localeStr.c_str());
    return result;
}

#define ConsoleWriteLn(data) std::cout<< data <<std::endl;

int main()
{
    ConsoleWriteLn(u8"UTC  : " + CurrentISO8601DateTime());
    ConsoleWriteLn(u8"LOCAL: " + CurrentISO8601DateTime(false));
}
```

---

**Results**

UTC  : 2020-04-12T17:00:18.632Z
LOCAL: 2020-04-12T12:00:18.633-0500

You can deserialize normally with [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 1):

With C++20, to control fraction part of second, we can use `time_point_cast`.

For .NET user, there is **no** "fff" equivalent in C++20. Using "fff" in format specification is the .NET style.

```
std::string strTime;
using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point tp_100ns = system_clock::from_time_t(SecondsSince1970);
auto tp_s = time_point_cast<seconds>(tp_100ns);

strTime = std::format("{:%FT%TZ}", tp_s);
// 2023-01-24T12:52:26T

strTime = std::format("{:%FT%TZ}", tp_100ns);
// 2023-01-24T12:52:26.0000000T
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it like this:

```
using namespace boost::posix_time;
ptime t = microsec_clock::universal_time();
qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(to_iso_extended_string(t) + "0Z"); // need 7 digits
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get local or UTC time:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::time_t time = std::time(0); // Get current time

    // Construct local time
    char loc[25];
    strftime(loc, sizeof(loc), "%FT%T%z", localtime(&time));

    // Construct UTC time 
    char utc[25];
    strftime(utc, sizeof(utc), "%FT%T%z", gmtime(&time));

    // Print local and UTC time
    std::cout << "Local time: " << loc << std::endl;
    std::cout << "UTC time: " << utc << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't suppend `Z` if it's not Zulu (UTC)

Answer (score 0):

I did this function:

- Compatible *ISO 8601*
- Having milliseconds (other solution does not have this)
- Having time zone
- C++11 only
- Without external lib such as *date*

(Amazing how it is hard to do simple stuffs)

**Result example**

```
2023-03-30T19:49:53.005+0200
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

std::string getISODateTime(const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& time)
{
    time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(time);
    tm tt2;

    localtime_s(&tt2, &tt); // If not recognized try: localtime_r(&tt, &tt2); !swapped params!

    // Get milliseconds hack
    auto timeTruncated = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(tt);
    int ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time - timeTruncated).count();

    return (std::stringstream()
        << std::put_time(&tt2, "%FT%T") // "2023-03-30T19:49:53"
        << "." << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << ms // ".005"
        << std::put_time(&tt2, "%z") // "+0200" (time zone offset, optional)
        ).str();
}


// Usage example
int main()
{
    std::cout << getISODateTime(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << std::endl;
}
```