# How to get datetime in ISO 8601 format on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, datetime, datetime-format, iso8601

What's a standard way to get a date time in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format on Windows using C++?  Specifically, I would like it to be formatted as:

`2017-02-22T10:00:00.123-05:00
2017-02-22T10:00:00.123   >>> -05:00 <<<    # how to print the offset?`

I was looking into combining the output of [`GetLocalTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetTimeZoneInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724421(v=vs.85).aspx), but this looks esoteric. There are similar questions on SO, however, I've not found a single one that prints UTC offset in a desired format. Is there a better approach?

Comment: [How do I construct an ISO 8601 datetime in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9527960/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I did see that, however, there is only [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19495751/706456) that prints the offset in the desired format 2017-02-22T10:00:00.123 **-05:00** and that answer use `Qt`, which I don't use. Maybe I am just missing a format specifier for it - most answers use `Z`, to denote the use of UTC time. What I need, however, is local time and an offset from UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this. We call `GetLocalTime` and `GetTimeZoneInformation` then pass it to the function which returns formatted string.

This is written quickly, not tested besides observing the fact it returns correct result on my machine **now**. It operates on the fact that `SYSTEMTIME` has a member `Bias` where `UTC = Localtime + Bias` and `Bias` is set in minutes. So get hours by dividing by 60 and taking absolute value of that. Then we get the minutes in similar way and set the sign depending on if `Bias > 0`

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

std::string format_system_time(const SYSTEMTIME& sys_time, const TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION& time_zone)
{
    std::ostringstream formatted_date_time;
    formatted_date_time << std::setfill('0');
    formatted_date_time << sys_time.wYear <<  "-" << std::setw(2) << sys_time.wMonth << "-" <<
        std::setw(2) << sys_time.wDay << "T" << std::setw(2) << sys_time.wHour << ":" <<
        std::setw(2) << sys_time.wMinute << ":" << std::setw(2) << sys_time.wSecond << "." <<
        std::setw(3) << sys_time.wMilliseconds;

    //UTC = localtime + bias; bias is in minutes
    int utc_offset_hours = time_zone.Bias / 60;
    int utc_offset_minutes = std::abs(time_zone.Bias - (utc_offset_hours * 60));
    char offset_sign = time_zone.Bias > 0 ? '-' : '+';
    formatted_date_time << offset_sign << std::setw(2) << std::abs(utc_offset_hours) << ":" << utc_offset_minutes;

    return formatted_date_time.str();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SYSTEMTIME date_and_time;
    GetLocalTime(&date_and_time);

    TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION time_zone;
    GetTimeZoneInformation(&time_zone);

    auto& formatted_date_time = format_system_time(date_and_time, time_zone);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time zones can have non-zero minute offsets.

Comment: @Anders Now that I'm looking I can see there are a lot of them, thanks for the info

Comment: Edited to take into account non-zero minute offsets.

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier %z gives you the timezone offset as described in the documentation (e.g. [MSDN on strftime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fe06s4ak.aspx)) but lefts out the ':'. You can use it like this to get the ':' into your string:

```
struct tm tmNow;

time_t now = time(NULL);    // Get the current time
_localtime64_s(&tmNow, &now);

char bufferTime[26];
char bufferTimezoneOffset[6];
size_t tsizTime =  strftime(bufferTime, 26, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", &tmNow);   // The current time formatted "2017-02-22T10:00:00"
size_t tsizOffset =  strftime(bufferTimezoneOffset, 6, "%z", &tmNow);       // The timezone offset -0500
strncpy_s(&bufferTime[tsizTime], 26, bufferTimezoneOffset, 3);              // Adds the hour part of the timezone offset
bufferTime[tsizTime + 3] = ':';                                             // insert ':'
strncpy_s(&bufferTime[tsizTime + 4], 26, &bufferTimezoneOffset[3], 3);      // Adds the minutes part of the timezone offset
puts(bufferTime);   // Your output: "2017-02-22T10:00:00-05:00"
```

I left out the milliseconds, as they are not part of the localtime as far as I know.

Comment: This is actually it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a drop-in solution for c++ on Windows. The closest you can get is `InternetTimeFromSystemTime` but it is only documented to support RFC1123.

You probably have to code it yourself with `GetLocalTime` + `GetTimeZoneInformation` + `wsprintf` (or `GetTimeZoneInformationForYear` if you are not dealing with the current time).

Comment: `GetSystemTime` returns time in UTC so there is no reason to add UTC offset to that.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), which works on VS-2013 and later, but does require some [installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation):

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    auto zt = make_zoned(current_zone(), floor<milliseconds>(system_clock::now()));
    cout << format("%FT%T%Ez\n", zt);
}
```

This just output for me:

```
2017-02-22T17:29:03.859-05:00
```