# Reasonable snprintf-like alternatives to strftime?

Tags: c++, c, date-formatting, strftime

Are there any standard (C, C++, POSIX, Linux...) alternatives to `strftime` which can be used to

1. calculate the required size of the string buffer for a given format and time,
2. truncate the output (instead of leaving the array contents undefined like `strftime` does) if buffer size is less than required for full output.

For example, `snprintf`-like semantics for date/time formatting which accept `strftime` format strings would do perfectly.

Functions like `std::put_time` in C++11 and later are not an option, because these may attempt to allocate extra memory dynamically and may throw exceptions.

Comment: Assume that someone will update your code in the next 7983 years, then count the number of bytes you need to format the time on your fingers. Doesn't really seem necessary to do it automatically. Just avoid long week and month names since they are locale dependent.

Comment: No, there isn't but you can write your own relatively easily. The [`stdarg.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/) and [`vsnprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsnprintf/) can be helpful to achieve that.

Comment: @Akira Well, it might be not so easy when it comes to weekday and month names according to current locale etc. stdarg and vsnprintf will not be necessary for the replacement, since strftime has a fixed number of arguments.

Comment: Why is dynamic memory allocation a problem? It would be easy: Allocate a buffer, try the strftime() if it fails, increase (double) the buffer size and iterate. You can even use a VLA on the stack if you want to avoid malloc()&co

Comment: Yes, 512 bytes should be long enough in any language I can think of.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy That depends on your format string, for each size you tell I can easily create one for you that exceeds it.

Comment: 64k  would not even make a dent in your heap

Comment: I would never do that sort of thing, personally. But I have worked with people who tried, so you have a point there.  His triple 1MB buffers allocated on the stack didn't do too well on embedded controllers, though.

Comment: If ISO 8601 style is OK, then you can use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527960/how-do-i-construct-an-iso-8601-datetime-in-c. Then the buffer size will not change.

Answer (score 2):

Could keep trying larger buffers until code succeeds (or decides this is too much).  The below uses a VLA (not C++), to sneakily avoid "attempt to allocate extra memory dynamically" - wink wink.

Simply allocating a large buffer, say `char buf[J_STRFTIME_MAX]`, should be sufficient for practical coding.  [@Michaël Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946592/reasonable-snprintf-like-alternatives-to-strftime/44951993#comment76869221_44946592) and avoid the iterative approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define J_STRFTIME_MAX 100

size_t j_strftime(char * s, size_t maxsize, const char * fmt, const struct tm * t) {
  size_t sz = strftime(s, maxsize, fmt, t);
  if (sz) {
    return sz;
  }
  size_t new_size = maxsize ? maxsize : 1;
  do {
    new_size *= 2;
    char new_s[new_size];
    sz = strftime(new_s, sizeof new_s, fmt, t);
    if (sz) {
      s[0] = 0;
      // strncat(s, new_s, maxsize);
      strncat(s, new_s, maxsize - 1);
      return strlen(new_s);
    }
  } while (sz < J_STRFTIME_MAX/2);
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  time_t now;
  time(&now);
  struct tm tm = *gmtime(&now);
  for (size_t i = 1; i < 30; i += 3) {
    char s[i];
    size_t sz = j_strftime(s, sizeof s, "%c", &tm);
    printf("%2zu %2zu <%s>\n", i, sz, s);
  }
}
```

Output

```
 1 24 <T>
 4 24 <Thu >
 7 24 <Thu Jul>
10 24 <Thu Jul  6>
13 24 <Thu Jul  6 14>
16 24 <Thu Jul  6 14:45>
19 24 <Thu Jul  6 14:45:00>
22 24 <Thu Jul  6 14:45:00 20>
25 24 <Thu Jul  6 14:45:00 2017>
28 24 <Thu Jul  6 14:45:00 2017>
```

Non-iterative

```
size_t j_strftime2(char * s, size_t maxsize, const char * fmt, const struct tm * t) {
  size_t sz = strftime(s, maxsize, fmt, t);
  if (sz == 0) {
    char new_s[J_STRFTIME_MAX];
    sz = strftime(new_s, sizeof new_s, fmt, t);
    if (sz == 0) {
      return 0;  // Too too big
    }
    s[0] = 0;
    // strncat(s, new_s, maxsize);
    strncat(s, new_s, maxsize - 1);
  }
  return sz;
}
```

[Edit] Code corrected.

Comment: To avoid unnecessary iterations, you could start with a larger value of `new_size`: `size_t new_size = maxsize > 128 ? maxsize : 128;`

Comment: `strftime` could fail for other reasons besides the destination buffer size, your approach would definitely have undefined behavior in this case.

Comment: @chqrlie True.  A nice direct approach.  Yet OP seemed to have an implied concern about memory usage, so the iterative approach creeps up.

Comment: Why not return `sz` in all cases, for the same semantics as `snprintf`? The user would allocate the minimum size in at most 2 steps (at the caller's level).

Comment: @chqrlie Agree about returning the size needed (not including \0).  Code amended.

Comment: @chqrlie The "other reasons" for failure are not detectable by the return value and as I see it are all problems with `strftime()` itself.  What is a sample failure of concern?

Comment: an invalid specifier, an invalid `tm` structure, a multibyte encoding error... You can handle these by setting an arbitrary maximum for `new_size` and return 0 if it is reached.

Comment: @chqrlie The "avoid unnecessary iterations" is handled when the user provides an ample sized buffer, which would be the usual expected code flow.  OP's unusual requirement seems to be geared toward exceptional cases.

Comment: @chqrlie " 
an invalid specifier" --> UB. C11 §7.27.3.5 6.  For `tm` with "values is outside the normal range", a prior call to the caller to `gmtime(),locatime()` can handle that.  Returning from `strftime()` anything special under the 3 conditions you mentioned is not specified, so I do not see "handle these by setting an arbitrary maximum" as  sufficient.