# Check if ISO 8601 date format is valid

Tags: c++, date, format, iso

How do I check if the date string is in ISO 8601 format(eg `2018-12-25T12:00:00+04:00`) in C++?
Tried using strptime to check if the date string is a valid ISO 8601 format but does not give me the correct result.

Comment: Please don't use `<ctime>` in C++ you have [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). Could you give an example which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: @TarickWelling Thanks for the response.I need to check if the date is valid/invalid.I used strptime("2019-06-24T09:00:00Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",&tm) to check if the given date is valid for the above format for which I get the result.Similarly how do I check if the date format with offset "2019-06-24T09:00:00+04:00" is valid or not?

Comment: What's the definition of "valid"? Is `2018-2-30T12:00:00:00` or `2018-2-20T25:00:00` valid? How about `2016-12-31T23:59:60` (with the presence of a leap second)?

Comment: @l.F. It seemed pretty clear from context that the OP meant "valid *as per the ISO 8601 date format standard*".  In other words, if other libraries/programs are expecting a "valid ISO 8601 formatted date", will his approach generate one that those libraries/programs will accept?

Comment: However, I believe this question should have been closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527960/how-do-i-construct-an-iso-8601-datetime-in-c (and I'm voting for it to be re-opened so it can be re-closed with that instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I'm aware of is to use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date lib](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

bool
is_valid(const std::string& s)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace date;
    istringstream in{s};
    local_seconds tp;
    in >> parse("%FT%T%Ez", tp);
    return !in.fail();
}

void
test(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << s << " is" << (is_valid(s) ? "" : " not") << " valid\n";
}

int
main()
{
    test("2018-12-25T12:00:00+04:00");
    test("2019-06-24T09:00:00+04:00");
    test("2018-2-30T12:00:00:00+04:00");
    test("2018-2-20T25:00:00+04:00");
    test("2016-12-31T23:59:60+04:00");
}
```

Output:

```
2018-12-25T12:00:00+04:00 is valid
2019-06-24T09:00:00+04:00 is valid
2018-2-30T12:00:00:00+04:00 is not valid
2018-2-20T25:00:00+04:00 is not valid
2016-12-31T23:59:60+04:00 is not valid
```

This does not allow for leap seconds, but if you're willing to install my time zone support library at the same link, it can do that too.  It does check for invalid syntax and invalid dates and times.