# Convert timestamp to the formatted date time using C++

Tags: c++, timestamp, c++14, c++-chrono, formatdatetime

I can only use C++ standard library (C++14) to convert timestamp to the given format date-time. I new to C++ and I know that C++ doesn't support us a lot via a library like Java. 
At a given date and time of **2011-03-10 11:23:56 in the Central European Time zone (CET)**, the following
standard-format output will be produced: "**2011-03-10T11:23:56.123+0100**".

```
std::string format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSSZ"; //default format
auto duration = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
auto timestamp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count();
```

My syntax for the format string would be

```
G : Era 
yy,yyyy : year (two digits/four digits) 
M,MM : month in number (without zero/ with zero) - (e.g.,1/01) 
MMM,MMMM : month in text (shortname/fullname)- (e.g.,jan/january) 
d,dd : day in month (without zero/with zero)- (e.g.,1/01) 
D : day in year
F : day of week of month
E, EEEE : day of week 
h,hh : hours(1-12) (without zero/with zero)- (e.g.,1/01) 
H,HH : hours(0-23) (without zero/with zero)- (e.g.,1/01) 
m,mm : minutes (without zero/with zero)- (e.g.,1/01) 
s,ss : seconds (without zero/with zero)- (e.g.,1/01) 
S,SS,SSS : milliseconds 
w,W : Week in year (without zero/with zero)- (e.g.,1/01) 
a : AM/PM 
z,zzzz : timezone name
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Stack overflow isn't a homework writing service. If it isn't homework just use the c++20 date library https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono also available at https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html

Comment: Maybe [std::put_time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) would be of use here?

Comment: @AlanBirtles What about "only C++ standard library (C++14)" makes you think he can use a C++ standard that is not even fully implemented yet?

Comment: Looks like you want to output timestamps in ISO 8601 format. If true, there should be some solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527960/how-do-i-construct-an-iso-8601-datetime-in-c

Comment: @eike i did read the question,i was trying to persuade him that unless he was doing homework he should change his stance and let someone else do the work for him by using a library

Comment: @AlanBirtles of course, it's not homework. Because my company doesn't allow to use C++ 20 that why I have to use C++14.

Comment: No reason not to use a library with a liberal licence though, try to persuade your company that you would be much more productive and your code much more reliable if you use available libraries rather than having to implement everything yourself

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so if I use C++20 do you have any suggest function or lib for me to use??

Comment: Use the date library I linked to above (which doesn't requrie c++20, it only needs c++11), examples in the question linked to by @Frodyne

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I construct an ISO 8601 datetime in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527960/how-do-i-construct-an-iso-8601-datetime-in-c)

Comment: ISO 8601 is my default format, but I want to convert timestamp to the format in which user input. In Java, I often use SimpleDateFormat which will receive input format and then convert the timestamp to that format. That is what I try to looking for in C++.

Comment: [Current date and time as string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358264/14065)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bit of tricky question because:

1. It isn't explicitly stated what the input is.  But from the example code I'm going to assume `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.
2. It is important to recognize that **Central European Time zone (CET)** is defined as a [time zone with a fixed UTC offset of 1h](https://24timezones.com/time-zone/cet#targetText=CET%20(Central%20European%20Time)%20is,%2B2)%20is%20in%20use.).  Some geographical regions follow this time zone rule year round, some do not.  And none have always followed it.  In any event, this part of the problem allows us to hard-code the UTC offset involved: 1h.  There is no daylight saving adjustment to make.

In C++14 there are two ways to do this without involving copyrighted (even open-source) 3rd party software:

1. Use the C API.
2. Roll your own.

The problem with 1 is that it is error prone.  It doesn't directly handle millisecond precision.  It doesn't directly handle specific time zones such as CET.  The C API only knows about UTC, and the computer's locally set time zone.  But these problems are surmountable.

The problem with 2 is that it involves non-intuitive arithmetic to extract the year, month and day fields from a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.

Despite the problems with 2, that is the solution I prefer and what I will present below.  I'll also show how C++20 will make this *much* easier.

In all solutions, I'll formalize the input and output by implementing a function of this form:

```
std::string format_CET(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp);
```

### Roll your own (C++14)

There are six discrete steps.  It will require these headers and no others:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
```

A. Shift the input by the +1 hour UTC offset.

```
// shift time_point to CET
tp += 1h;
```

A function-local using directive is convenient to bring the UDL `h` into scope, and everything else that will be needed from `<chrono>` within this function:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
```

B.  Get two variations of the `time_point tp`:  One with millisecond precision and one with day precision:

```
// Get time_points with both millisecond and day precision
auto tp_ms = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(tp);
auto tp_d = time_point_cast<days>(tp_ms);
```

It is important to understand that these two casts *round towards zero*, and will give incorrect results for negative time points.  `system_clock` gives negative time points prior to its epoch of 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  C++17 introduces `floor<millliseconds>(tp)` which fixes this problem.

The day-precision `time_point` will be used to extract the year, month and day fields, and the millisecond-precision `time_point` will be used to extract the hour, minute, second and millisecond fields.  The `duration days` used above won't be added until C++20, but you can do it with:

```
using days = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>>;
```

C.  To get the year, month and day fields from `tp_d` it is convenient to use one of the [public domain algorithms for calendrical operations](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#civil_from_days).  This is not a 3rd party library.  It is algorithms for writing your own calendrical libraries (which is what I'm in the middle of explaining).  I have customized the `civil_from_days` algorithm to exactly fix the needs of `format_CET`:

```
// Get {y, m, d} from tp_d
auto z = tp_d.time_since_epoch().count();
static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
         "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
static_assert(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits >= 20,
         "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
z += 719468;
const int era = (z >= 0 ? z : z - 146096) / 146097;
const unsigned doe = static_cast<unsigned>(z - era * 146097);          // [0, 146096]
const unsigned yoe = (doe - doe/1460 + doe/36524 - doe/146096) / 365;  // [0, 399]
int y = static_cast<int>(yoe) + era * 400;
const unsigned doy = doe - (365*yoe + yoe/4 - yoe/100);                // [0, 365]
const unsigned mp = (5*doy + 2)/153;                                   // [0, 11]
const unsigned d = doy - (153*mp+2)/5 + 1;                             // [1, 31]
const unsigned m = mp + (mp < 10 ? 3 : -9);                            // [1, 12]
y += (m <= 2);
```

There is an exhaustingly detailed derivation of this algorithm at the site linked above for those who want to know how it works.

At this point, the integral variables `{y, m, d}` contain the year, month, day triple.

D.  Get the time duration since the local midnight.  This will be used to extract the local time of day:

```
// Get milliseconds since the local midnight
auto ms = tp_ms - tp_d;
```

E.  Get the hour, minute, second and millisecond fields:

```
// Get {h, M, s, ms} from milliseconds since midnight
auto h = duration_cast<hours>(ms);
ms -= h;
auto M = duration_cast<minutes>(ms);
ms -= M;
auto s = duration_cast<seconds>(ms);
ms -= s;
```

At this point, the `chrono::duration` variables `{h, M, s, ms}` hold the desired values.

F.  Now we're ready to format:

```
// Format {y, m, d, h, M, s, ms} as yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSS+0100
std::ostringstream os;
os.fill('0');
os << std::setw(4) << y << '-' << std::setw(2) << m << '-' << std::setw(2)
   << d << 'T' << std::setw(2) << h.count() << ':'
   << std::setw(2) << M.count() << ':' << std::setw(2) << s.count()
   << '.' << std::setw(3) << ms.count() << "+0100";
return os.str();
```

Using a combination of the manipulator `setw` to set the width of each field, with a fill character of `0`, one gets the desired leading zeroes.

### The C++20 solution

This is *much* easier in the C++20 spec:

```
std::string
format_CET(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    static auto const CET = locate_zone("Etc/GMT-1");
    return std::format("{:%FT%T%z}", zoned_time{CET, floor<milliseconds>(tp)});
}
```

"Etc/GMT-1" is the IANA equivalent of **Central European Time zone (CET)**.  This `time_zone const*` is located and stored in the variable `CET`.  The `time_point tp` is truncated to millisecond-precision, and paired with the `time_zone` using a `zoned_time`.  This `zoned_time` is then formatted (to millisecond precision) using the format string shown.

There exists an open-source (MIT license) preview of the C++20 spec with very minor syntax differences [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

```
#include "date/tz.h"

std::string
format_CET(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    static auto const CET = locate_zone("Etc/GMT-1");
    return format("%FT%T%z", zoned_time<milliseconds>{CET, floor<milliseconds>(tp)});
}
```

[Some installation is required for Windows.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)

This preview does work with C++14.  In C++17 and later `zoned_time<milliseconds>` can be simplified to just `zoned_time`.

### Custom time zone support

There is also a way to use the preview library such that no installation is required.  It becomes a *header-only* library.  This is done by creating a custom time zone that models just CET, and then install that in the `zoned_time`.  Here is what the custom time zone could look like:

```
#include "date/tz.h"

class CET
{
public:

    template <class Duration>
        auto
        to_local(date::sys_time<Duration> tp) const
        {
            using namespace date;
            using namespace std::chrono;
            return local_time<Duration>{(tp + 1h).time_since_epoch()};
        }

    template <class Duration>
        auto
        to_sys(date::local_time<Duration> tp) const
        {
            using namespace date;
            using namespace std::chrono;
            return sys_time<Duration>{(tp - 1h).time_since_epoch()};
        }

    template <class Duration>
        date::sys_info
        get_info(date::sys_time<Duration>) const
        {
            using namespace date;
            using namespace std::chrono;
            return {ceil<seconds>(sys_time<milliseconds>::min()),
                    floor<seconds>(sys_time<milliseconds>::max()),
                    1h, 0min, "CET"};
        }

    const CET* operator->() const {return this;}
};
```

`CET` now meets enough of the time zone requirements that it can be used within `zoned_time` and formatted as before.  In C++14, the syntax is complicated by having to explicitly specify the `zoned_time` template arguments:

```
std::string
format_CET(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using ZT = zoned_time<milliseconds, CET>;
    return format("%FT%T%z", ZT{CET{}, floor<milliseconds>(tp)});
}
```

This option is also in the C++20 spec, and its advantage is that the time zone abbreviation (which is unused in your problem) will correctly report "CET" instead of "+01".

More documentation on custom time zones is found [here](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Examples).

With any of these solutions, the function can now be exercised like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << format_CET(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << '\n';
}
```

And a typical output looks like this:

```
2019-10-29T16:37:51.217+0100
```

Comment: Very clearly and understandable, thanks a lot sir. What I must do next is to format the output stream. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Yes.  See paragraph `F.` under the subheading "Roll your own (C++14)" of my answer.

Comment: What do you think about strftime() function is defined in <ctime> header file. Because my input format syntax is the same as Java's SimpleDateformat., so do you think this function can do what I'm trying right now?

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do is just like a library in Java name "SimpleDateFormat". Input is a timestamps string and format string. The output will be the formatted date. I'm a newb to C++ also. I have also edited my post.

Comment: Interesting twist to your question.  `strftime` can handle most of this but not all.  `strftime` is limited to 1s precision.  It has no support for time zone names, though it does have support for time zone abbreviations and time zone UTC offsets.  The support for the latter two is not guaranteed by the standard.  However since you only need to deal with "CET", this should not be a significant obstacle since you can hard-code names and offsets.  You can also write custom code to place the milliseconds field wherever you want.  There is no direct replacement for Java's    SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Yes I know that `strftime` only support to 1s but I can do it to milliseconds now. What I have to do next to finish my work is that to format the syntax from SimpleDateFormat to fit with `strftime`

Comment: I have edited my post, can you help me to find a solution to do that also??

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    auto t = std::time(nullptr);
    auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);
    std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%z%Z") << "\n";
}
----
2019-10-29T05:05:14.-0700PDT
```