# Create Json object encoded with current date and time

Tags: c++

I am really new to Json. I tried doing this so that I could print current date and time but did not work.

```
using json = nlohmann::json;
json j;
j["chrono"]={ctime}
std::cout<<j.dump()<<std::endl;
```

Comment: "Did not work" means what? Computer caught on fire? Got the wrong output? Wouldn't compile? Dog ran away? Anything in terms of *technical specifics* helps narrow down the problem to what's actually going wrong, and from there we can help with a solution.

Comment: Please show a [mre] with full compilable code, the expected output and the actual output

Answer (score 3):

JSON doesn't have a special time data type, but a de facto standard (also used by Javascript) is to use ISO 8601 strings to store dates in JSON documents.

So your real question is "how can I format the current time as ISO 8601". Using the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9528166/1863938

```cpp
time_t now;
time(&now);
char buf[sizeof "2011-10-08T07:07:09Z"];
strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%FT%TZ", gmtime(&now));
```

You can then easily adapt your code:

```cpp
json j;
j["chrono"]={buf}
std::cout<<j.dump()<<std::endl;
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/9eAXbn