# Convert unix microseconds to ISO 8601 date time string in C++

Tags: c++, string, unix-timestamp, c++-chrono, iso8601

**Problem**:

I got a signed integer 64-bit variable of unix time with microseconds.
I want to convert that to ISO 8601 Date time format.
The format must be stored in a string in C++.

Notice that this is microseconds and not seconds and the output must be a string and not stream.

I begin with my time point

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timePoint
```

Which I convert to microseconds in unix time.

```
std::chrono::system_clock::duration duration = timePoint.time_since_epoch();
int64_t microsecondsUnixTime = duration.count()/10;
```

And now I need to convert `microsecondsUnixTime` to date time in the format ISO 8601 as a string only.

Comment: added the `chrono` tag because those who are good with it (and its creators have been known to stalk these halls) can probably show you a trick to go straight from the `time_point` to ISO 8601 in a couple simple steps. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43690698/4581301) looks like it only needs a small tweak. On re-read, no tweak required. Give it a try and let me know if we can close as a duplicate.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the reply. I have been searching for how to convert microseconds unix time to ISO 8601 in a string.

Comment: The question states you are starting with a `time_point`, not unix-ish time. My suggestion is you skip the unix-ish time stage completely. If you start with unix-ish time, obviously such advice is pointless and you should revise the question to remove the `time_point`. You should also look into [`std::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) and add on the microseconds yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide `microsecondsUnixTime` by 10<sup>6</sup> you can use `std::strftime()` to generate the string to 1 second resolution, then append the fractional part for microsecond resolution:

```
int fraction_sec = microsecondsUnixTime % 1000000u ;
time_t seconds = microsecondsUnixTime / 1000000u ;

char timestr_sec[] = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.ssssss" ;
std::strftime( timestr_sec, sizeof(timestr_sec) - 1, 
               "%F %T", std::gmtime(&seconds) ) ;
std::ostringstream  tout ;
tout << timestr_sec << '.' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(6) << fraction_sec ;    
std::string timestr_micro = tout.str() ;

std::cout << timestr_micro ;
```

Output example:

```
2022-12-07 20:25:18.860289
```